# Check if sass variable is used in VS

Tags: visual-studio, sass, intellisense

Is there any VS extension that checks if a sass-variable is used in other sass-files. It would be nice to have VS detect if a variable is used or not.

Comment: `variable-exists()`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any VS extension that checks if a sass-variable is used in
> other sass-files. It would be nice to have VS detect if a variable is
> used or not.

**I am afraid that you can not get what you want so far.**

**CASS** files are not as flexible as you think. And there is no such vs extension that has the ability to check if the cass variables are used in other cass files.

If you still want the feature, I suggest you could [suggest a feature on our User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8). When you finishing it, you could share the link here and anyone who is interested in it will vote it. And all of these will get more attention from **Microsoft** which will give you a satisfactory reply as soon as possible.